# What does this mean: `Rebasing (1/4)` when I do `pull -v --rebase=merges`, when there is only one commit?

Tags: git

I have next commits:

```
* be23d923d (HEAD -> bot) Dump more info
* 506b1b5a7 (office/bot) Fix IP for registry.gitlab.office
* fb7e89677 Show build log on failure
*   58c2e3606 Merge branch 'implement_test' into test2
```

After running `git pull -v --rebase=merges`, the result is:

```
* 42852fd6b (HEAD -> bot) Dump more info
* a3c657c09 (office/bot) Echo $IMAGE_TAG
* 506b1b5a7 Fix IP for registry.gitlab.office
* fb7e89677 Show build log on failure
*   58c2e3606 Merge branch 'implement_test' into test2
```

Here is the log of that command:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 287 bytes | 287.00 KiB/s, done.
From office-repo:office/bot
   506b1b5a7..a3c657c09  bot        -> office/bot
 = [up to date]          prod       -> office/prod
Changes from 506b1b5a7ebcf0e9778279f5de90bd67c0462e0a to a3c657c099ea0077a22d77de10029dd35be1058d:
 .gitlab-ci.yml | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Rebasing (1/4)
Rebasing (2/4)
Rebasing (3/4)
 .gitlab-ci.yml | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/bot.
```

We can see that there is only on commit on the remote repository:

```
git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines --full-history 506b1b5a7..a3c657c09
commit a3c657c099ea0077a22d77de10029dd35be1058d (office/bot)
Author: Administrator <admin@example.com>
Date:   Sun Dec 18 15:54:06 2022 +0000

    Echo $IMAGE_TAG

diff --git a/.gitlab-ci.yml b/.gitlab-ci.yml
index 4ca4f8769..e4e25a947 100644
--- a/.gitlab-ci.yml
+++ b/.gitlab-ci.yml
@@ -23,6 +23,7 @@ build-job:
     - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --pass>
     - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
     - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
+    - echo $IMAGE_TAG
 
 test-job1:
   stage: test
```

Why are there three rebases when I would expect one?
Also Git ommits the last rebase?
(It shows 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 and there is no `Rebase 4/4`)

Comment: I have reproduced your output, this is truly bizarre. It's rebasing one commit (in your example and the one I recreated), so I don't understand the log at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `--rebase=merges` here, which means your pull command is using a `git rebase --rebase-merges` to do the rebasing.

If you test with just `git pull -v --rebase` you'll see a single rebase step as you would expect.

But with `--rebase=merges`, you can break it down with a `git fetch` followed by `git rebase --rebase-merges -i office/bot`. The `-i` will let us see the rebase steps it's going to apply.

This is what I get in my simulated case:

```
label onto

reset onto
pick 2f840de bar
```

and that means 4 instructions for the rebase. It's still that the blank line is considered an instruction, but I confirmed it is: if you delete the blank line, the rebase logs show `(n/3)` instead of `(n/4)`.

Those extra steps are needed to handle merges should there have been any. In this case, there aren't any, but the steps are still there because I guess `git rebase --rebase-merges` doesn't optimize them out even when it sees there are no merges.

Comment: Yeah, empty line is not a command. It looks like a bug or not completely implemented feature.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the command length is calculated with a simple line count, but then empty lines are skipped and don't count as steps, so you end up being done at 3/4. Just a minor bug, I say.